# Ubuntu 10.04 Development Tools

Tags: ubuntu, installation, development-environment, ubuntu-10.04

I needed to install Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 for my dev work. I found that it does not install most of the dev tools/packages by default.

1. What are the essential dev tools one needs? I don't mind installing them all for the sake of not wanting to have build failure later on for some third part package.
2. Also any documentation where I can get a list of essential packages. E.g:I found that mysql-devel rpm in fedora is called 'libmysql++-dev' in Ubuntu. I am looking for such querks

Comment: What sort of development are you doing?  Language?  What sort of applications?  Are you migrating from a specific environment?

Comment: What kind of development do you want to do? C, C++, Python, Java, ...

Comment: I do dev on C/C++/Python/mysql. also I have already done sudo apt-get build-essential

Comment: for now Matt's answer seems enough for me... Waiting if I get any other stellar answer from a Ubuntu fanatic...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with `build-essential`. Presumably you're after C/C++ stuff. Don't forget:

- g++
- libboost-dev
- libgtk2.0-dev
- libmysqlclient-dev
- python-dev

To install the necessary dev files to build a given package, run the command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
```

For example:

```
matt@stanley:~/cpfs$ sudo apt-get build-dep pidgin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting libltdl-dev instead of libltdl3-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  doxygen libenchant-dev libgadu-dev libgstfarsight0.10-dev libgtkspell-dev
  libidn11-dev libltdl-dev libmeanwhile-dev libncursesw5-dev libnm-util-dev
  libnspr4-dev libnss3-dev libperl-dev libsasl2-dev libsilc-dev libsqlite3-dev
  libstartup-notification0-dev libxss-dev libzephyr-dev network-manager-dev
  tcl tcl-dev tcl8.4-dev tk tk-dev tk8.4-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev
0 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.3MB of archives.
After this operation, 60.3MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, most packages have a development version. By convention the names of theseare the very same, but have an `-dev` sticked to the end. If you're interested, you can also get the source-code for any package from the repo (`sudo apt-get source ...`) and even let apt automatically build it. Check out the manpage of `apt-get` for specific details.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
apt-cache search <package or tools>
```

You don't need to run this as root or sudoed. Through this manner you can find the correct package name.